# Access Chrome API in service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I'm trying to show the  [chrome rich notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications) from my ServiceWorker but apparently I cannot access chrome api.

Is there a specific reason why this is not possible or is there a work around this?

Right now I am displaying notifications using [ServiceWorker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) by calling `ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification()` but this API can only do classic simple notifications.

Comment: Should be closed - indeed as shown in the first answer, the mentioned API belongs to Chrome Apps - so the question does not make sense in this context.

Answer (score 2):

That API belongs to *Chrome Apps*, it is not meant for website.

Indeed the documentation you linked is under the section *Apps*.